# Text and image side-by-side inside \thanks

Tags: graphics, footnotes

I have to thank my sponsor and also give their logo in my paper. However \thank does not go with \minipage or \makebox so I cannot have the body of text and the logo side by side. Instead I have the image below the text.

```
\documentclass[runningheads,final]{llncs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}
\author{Some authors%
\thanks{\lipsum[1][1-3]%
\protect\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}%
}}
%
\institute{Some institute}
%

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass[runningheads,final]{llncs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}
\author{Some authors
\thanks{\protect\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}
This is text for footnote}}

\institute{Some institute}
%

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: How does this differ from the MWE posted in the question?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Did you make a typo? I need both text and image in the footnote.

Comment: @campa `OP'`s provided `MWE` having compilation error, also I gave the suggestion based on my understanding, excuse me if my understand is wrong...

Comment: @Faustus please check the edited `MWE`...